# Unable to make NginX load balancing

Tags: wcf, nginx, load-balancing

I am new to the nginx config.

I am trying to do a load balancing example with nginx and wcf rest service in windows platform.

Here is what I have in my **conf/nginx.conf** file:-

```
upstream servers_customserver {
server 127.0.0.1:62133; 
server 127.0.0.1:64897;
server 127.0.0.1:64921;
}

server {
listen 8070;       

location /test {
proxy_pass  http://servers_customserver/;             
}
```

My motive is whenever, I try to enter a website name which contains "/test" then redirect to one of the urls in the 
"servers_customserver".

Nginx is fine in localhost:8070.

But whenever I did localhost:8070/test, I am getting "404 Not Found nginx/1.12.0" in the browser. I am sure that my services are up.

Do, I need to work with my services in IIS or any webservers to make this to work?

Could some one guide me in solving this error.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you give here access logs as well ? I guess the last slash on your proxy_pass might be the problem try `proxy_pass  http://servers_customserver;`

Comment: @zochamx. Thx for the reply. I tried removing "/" but still not solving this problem. 
Access Log: 127.0.0.1 - - [31/Jul/2017:10:44:50 +0530] "GET /test HTTP/1.1" 404 571 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36"
Error Log: 2017/07/31 10:44:50 [error] 9148#7844: *79 CreateFile() "F:\IDE\Visual Studio Collection\Web Servers\nginx-1.12.0\nginx-1.12.0/html/test" failed (2: The system cannot find the file specified), client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /test HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8070"
Thx.

Comment: @zochamx: I have noticed both kind of slash "/" and "\" in the error log. "....nginx-1.12.0/html/test" failed ...." Is this is a root cause? In mean time, created a empty file in that "html" folder named test.html for checking. Still facing the same. Any other issues. Thx in adv.

Comment: Oh you are on windows! Ok let's see, from your logs it seems that nginx doesn't match your location otherwise you would see the proxy request on the logs. Can you give the whole config file? For example do you close the server block properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luckily,

After adding the following steps to the location block, the load balancing stuff works for me.

```
        proxy_set_header   Host   $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host @server_name;   
        proxy_redirect off;
```

Thanks.